# Look up for a text in json result in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, error-handling

Want to add condition if the response message in the json result has the text 'error' then do some operations.

I have a function in my controller file that is used to fill the data however when there is an internal error like a user defined value that I want to consider as an error I am classifying it by concatenating the word error in the result and passing it as json result to use it in ajax call. I tried using indexOf in the message variable however everytime I am getting -1 whether the result received on ajax call has "Error" or not.

This is my C# code for getting data and passing the json result.

```
public List<string> PowerShellExecutorGrd(string scriptPath, string arg)
    {
        var items = new List<string>();
        using (var shell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath).AddArgument(arg);
            var results = shell.Invoke();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(shell.HadErrors.ToString());
            if (shell.HadErrors == false) {
                if (results.Any()) {
                    foreach (var psObj in results)
                        items.Add(Server.HtmlEncode(psObj.ToString().Trim('{', '}')));
                }
            } else
            {
                var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (ErrorRecord err in shell.Streams.Error)
                {
                    errorMessage.AppendLine(err.ToString());
                }
                items.Add("Error : " + errorMessage.ToString());
            }
        };
        return items;
    }


public JsonResult FillMembers(string GroupGUID)
    {
        var SDC = PowerShellExecutorGrd(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get-ADGroupMembers.ps1", GroupGUID);
        return Json(new { message = SDC }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Group/FillMembers",
                    data: { GroupGUID: $("#ddlGroup option:selected").val() },
                    success: function (response) {
                          if ($.parseJSON(response.message).indexOf("Error") == -1) { alert(response.message); }
                    }
        }
  });
```

Suppose my shell script has 1/0, the json result will have Divide by Zero error encountered, I am getting it in response.message however the indexOf() property is not seems to be working.

Comment: `indexOf` is a String/Array operator.  Parsing the json turns it into **not** a string.  Is the JSON response an array?

Comment: Yes, its a list<string>. The PowerShellExecutoreGrd handles the error text into that list variable.

Comment: `console.log(response)` and verify that it has a property of `message` on it, and that `response` is not a String

Comment: And you aren't parsing the json....you are trying to look for an object property in the response string and parse that. But the response string would have no such property. Add `dataType:'json'`, to request options and get rid of `$.parseJSON`. The whole response will be an object that way

Comment: @Taplar, message is created in the FillMembers function as a new variable.

Comment: @charlietfl, I tried response.message.indexOf("Error") still it gives -1 always.

Comment: So what does `response` actually look like?

Comment: FillMembers is on the server side.  I'm suggesting you verify what `response` actually is.  You're assuming that response is an object with a property of message on it.  I'm pointing out that that is an assumption.  Edit: And if all your assumptions are correct, the code would work and you wouldn't be asking a question here, :)

Comment: response is [object Object].

Comment: And what is `console.log(response.message)`?

Comment: The text that I am setting in items. "Error: Attempted to divide by zero."

Comment: So that's not JSON.  `response.message.startsWith('Error: ')`

Comment: But FillMembers returns the JSON Result?

Comment: That means nothing.  Your console log is telling you want it is.  The fact that `response` is already parsed into an object suggests that jQuery is auto parsing it for you already.  It will do that if the response returns a content type of application/json on it

Comment: ^^^ you can check that by looking at the request in the developer tools network tab and looking at the content type header on the response

Comment: @Taplar, thank you so much for the info. Yes, looked at it and found out that datatype of response.message is undefined which is why even the indexOf was not working.